# How to get the matching version of shared preferences, upgradder and other packages?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem on matters upgrader, it's seems i can't build my apps when it come to difference version off package

here is the problem

```
      Running "flutter pub get" in Mobile7Merge...                    
      Because requests 3.3.0 depends on shared_preferences ^0.5.2 and no versions of requests match >3.3.0 <4.0.0, requests ^3.3.0 requires shared_preferences ^0.5.2.

      So, because mobile7 depends on both requests ^3.3.0 and shared_preferences ^2.0.3, version solving failed.
      pub get failed (1; So, because mobile7 depends on both requests ^3.3.0 and shared_preferences ^2.0.3, version solving failed.)
```

here is my **pubspec.yaml**

```
      name: mobile7
  description: Mobile 7
  version: 1.0.0+1

  environment:
    sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"

  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    http: ^0.12.1
    lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.1.0
    flutter_appauth: ^0.9.1
    flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
    fl_chart: ^0.10.1
    flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.8
    intl: ^0.16.1
    google_nav_bar: ^2.2.0
    line_icons: ^0.2.0
    google_fonts: ^1.1.0
    equatable: ^1.2.5
    bloc: ^6.0.3
    flutter_bloc: ^6.0.5
    rxdart: ^0.23.1
    expandable: ^4.1.4
    jiffy: ^3.0.1
    requests: ^3.3.0
    flutter_html: ^1.0.0
    webview_flutter: any
    flutter_downloader: ^1.4.4
    path_provider: ^1.6.24
    permission_handler: ^5.0.1
    fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
    # flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.3.0
    # flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.0+10
    upgrader: ^3.0.0
    dio: any
    advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.2.0
    pinch_zoom: ^0.0.4
    dart_date: ^1.0.7
    flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4
    shared_preferences: ^2.0.3
    # shared_preferences: ^0.5.2


  dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter

  flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
    assets:
      - images/
```

I thought to have two package at the same time, that is 2.0.3 and 0.5.2 but either any of them have solve my problem, i tried to search if i can use two package with the same name but mainly, thos shared_preference are inside request package and upgrader package, i tried to include there on my own
How can i solve this??

Answer (score 0):

Managing dependencies can be a pain some times but I have found this commands can be useful:

- `flutter pub outdated` https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated
- `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-upgrade#--major-versions

Comment: I still got the same error, here like this `Because mobile7 depends on requests >=3.3.0 which depends on shared_preferences ^0.5.2, shared_preferences ^0.5.2 is required.So, because mobile7 depends on shared_preferences >=2.0.3, version solving failed.`

Comment: Then try dependency_overrides. Here's the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#conflict-resolution